# How to throttle checkbox check & uncheck actions

Tags: javascript, checkbox, throttling

May I know how can I throttle checkbox check & uncheck actions to prevent users click checkbox and change the check & uncheck too frequently? How to use the throttle function to control the check & uncheck action? For example, we only change check & uncheck at most every 2000ms even user click 100 times.
reference: https://towardsdev.com/debouncing-and-throttling-in-javascript-8862efe2b563

```js
const throttle = (func, limit) => {
  let inThrottle;
  return function() {
    if (!inThrottle) {
      func();
      inThrottle = true;
      setTimeout(() => inThrottle = false, limit);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type = "checkbox" id = "checkbox1">
<label for="checkAll">Checkbox 1</label>
```

Comment: So what is the "real" problem?

Comment: In other words, what are you trying to prevent by slowing users down? Personally, I'd be really annoyed if I found a site that started messing with my ability to check checkboxes as fast as I wanted to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` to control the check/uncheck action.

```js
const throttle = (func, limit) => {
  let inThrottle;
  
  return function(e) {
    if (inThrottle) {
      return e.preventDefault();  // Prevents check/uncheck of the input
    }
    
    func();
    inThrottle = true;
    setTimeout(() => inThrottle = false, limit);
  }
}

function clickHandler() {}

document.getElementById("checkbox1").addEventListener("click", throttle(clickHandler, 2000))
```

```html
<input type = "checkbox" id = "checkbox1">
<label for="checkAll">Checkbox 1 (Can only be changed every 2s)</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.now()` and measure the milliseconds.

```js
const c = document.getElementById("c");

const throttleMs = 500; // how much you'd like to throttle in milliseconds
let lastClick = Date.now();
c.addEventListener("change", e => {
  // check if last date - current date is less than 500ms
  if (Date.now() - lastClick < throttleMs) {
    c.checked = !c.checked; // e.preventDefault() doesn't work for checkboxes
  }
  lastClick = Date.now();
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="c" />
```

Comment: I believe the user is asking how to apply the throttle function they already have to the problem at hand, not how to throttle in general.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I just tried it but it looks more like debounce, not throttle?  if I keep clicking vary fast,  it does not change status, only when I stop and then click it changes. May I know how to make it  not matter how many times it's clicked, it only changes status at most every 2000ms?